# Syntax Error en print

Tags: python, sintaxis

Soy nuevo usando Python asi que estoy tomando un curso. Nuestro reto era hacer un pequeño programa que calcula en que año vas a cumplir 100 años. En la linea 8 me marca un error en la sintaxis, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Aquí está mi código:

```
import string
import random
import age

date = 2017+100
name = input("Enter your name: ")
print()
age = int(input("Enter your age: ")

print ("So, you will be 100 years old in " + age + -(int(date)))
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: `import age`  no debería ir ya que más adelante se asigna el valor a la variable. y le hace falta un paréntesis al final el input `age = int(input("Enter your age: "))`

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("So, you will be 100 years old in " + age + -(int(date)))
```

Esta linea está mal porque concatenas dos `int` con un `string` y no se puede en python. Si quisieras unir el texto con age y date necesitas convertir a `string` dichas variables.
Sería algo así:

```
print ("So, you will be 100 years old in " + str(age) + "-" + str(date))
```

O también podrías usar `format` que es lo mejor para el formateo de textos.

```
print ("So, you will be 100 years old in {} -{}".format(age, date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas veces es bueno tener en cuenta cómo quieres que sea tu programa, ya que python permite hacer algo que por ejemplo en C, te llevaría 10 líneas a solo dos. Entonces, resolviendo tu duda, el print() que tienes ahí en la línea 7 no sirve para nada, como las importaciones que haces, pues no veo que uses random.
Yo haría así el programa, basándome en lo que tienes escrito.

```
def Age(): #Así se define una función, para llamarla solo ingresa Age()
    resp = 'a' #Bandera para que inicie el programa
    while resp != 'Y':
    name = input("Enter u name: \n")
    age  = int(input("Enter u age: \n"))
    aux  = (100-age) + 2017
    print("So, ",name, " u'll b 100 yrs old in ", aux)
    resp = input("Do u finished Y/N:\n")
```

Saludos y sigue jugando con python